# How to redirect deleted, expired, and disabled pages to site home page in DNN?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I'm using the Advanced URL Management option for my DNN site and would like to use the AUM_DeletedTabHandlingType (in database table PortalSettings) to redirect deleted, expired & disabled pages to the site home page.

By default, this is set to '0' in the database, but I can't seem to find any documentation explaining what the options are. I have tried setting it to '1' and '2' with no luck.

Is this a working feature in DNN? If not, is there another way to redirect these old pages to the home page?

Comment: That would be a pretty disasterous thing to do, though.

Comment: Having a hard time seeing why this would be "disastrous".

Comment: Well, then instead of a useful 410 response, users would be confusingly bounced off to the home page, which isn't what they wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From this page](https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-3487), I came across

•deletedTabHandling - 'Do301RedirectToPortalHome' or 'Do404Error'. Specifies what response to give when a deleted (but not emptied from recycle bin) tab is found. Once a tab is emptied from the recycle bin, a 404 will be returned, unless a custom redirect has been created for that tab path.

So I would imagine that you'll need to configure the old URLs to redirect to the homepage manually, if you've removed them from the recycle bin.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I would love a way to redirect certain expired pages to the homepage, or some other specified page. For example, promotional landing pages that are given an expiration date. Do you know of an extension that could do this?

Comment: I don't know of any extensions that will do that.